How to connect to rabbit mqtt running on linux vm from another server using c#
I am trying to connect to a Rabbit mqtt which is running on linux vm. I need to publish to it from another server using c# program which was not working. I get the below error
Unhandled exception. RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException: None of the specified endpoints were reachable

string ipAddress = "19.167.17.**";
            string username = "admin";
            string password = "admin";
            ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
            factory.Uri = new Uri($"amqp://admin:rabbitmqtt@{ipAddress}:5672");
            factory.ClientProvidedName = "Testing1";
            IConnection cnn = factory.CreateConnection();
            if (cnn.IsOpen)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Connection to rabbitmq is successfull. . .");
                IModel channel = cnn.CreateModel();
                channel.ConfirmSelect();
                string exchangeName = "DemoExchange";
                string routingKey = "demo-routing-key";
                string queueName = "DemoQueue";
                channel.ExchangeDeclare(exchangeName, ExchangeType.Direct); 
                channel.QueueDeclare(queueName, false, false, false, null); 
                channel.QueueBind(queueName, exchangeName, routingKey, null);
                string messagestring = $"Hello world -> testing {DateTime.Now.ToString("g")} Rabbit MqTT";

                DateTime timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow;
                string timestampAsString = timestamp.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

                // Message properties
                var properties = channel.CreateBasicProperties();
                properties.Headers = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                properties.Headers.Add("Timestamp", timestampAsString);

                //properties.Headers.Add("Id", "JobReqID");

                byte[] messageBodyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(messagestring);
                channel.BasicPublish(exchangeName, routingKey, basicProperties: properties, messageBodyBytes); // publishes a message to RabbitMQ .

                if (channel.WaitForConfirms(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Message Sent successfully");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error sending message");
                }
                channel.Close();
                cnn.Dispose();

Above code I tried and it started to throw the exception as no endpoints where reachable
Could anyone help me to solve this issue. and I am unable to change the mqtt config. If I tried changing it I am unable to start the mqtt service.
